# How do I pass a list of objects from a WCF service to an ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am trying to pass a list from my WCF service to my ASP.NET web app.

First I passed a usual list of objects and used `System.Collections.Generic.List` in my configuration, everything worked out just fine.

Now I changed my code and made an object out of my list.
The class looks like this:

```
public class Persons : List<Person>
{
    private List<Person> personlist;

    public Persons()
    {
        personlist = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Now I struggle with the configurations.
What do I have to change in my configurations?
I set the collections type to: `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`
and my client isn't giving me an error:

```
WCF.Persons personlist = client.GetPersonList(@"C:\example");
```

But when I run the application I get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WCFasp.net.WCF.Persons', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WCFasp.net.WCF.Person]'.

Is it even possible to pass such a thing? And where do I have to make the changes?

I searched a lot for a good answer but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wcf client code is fine, the problem is in the view, as it only understands object of type `List<Person>`, you can up cast it to Base type which is `List<Person>`  that before passing it to view like:

```
WCF.Persons personlist = client.GetPersonList(@"C:\example"); 

return View(personlist as List<Person>);
```

and your View is strongly typed to `List<Person>` i suspect :

```
@model List<Person>
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the model binding in the view to the new object

Comment: yes, you have both options, depends what is suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

```
WCF.Persons persons = client.GetPersonList(@"C:\example"); 

return View(persons);
```

your view should be as follows

```
@model WCF.Persons

@foreach(var person in Model)
{ 
@person
}
```